# Django creating reusable app that loads specific js

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a django reusable app that will basically contain bunch of template tags.

How and what are the best practices for allowing app-specific js to be easily loaded using the app.

Is there a way a user can just put `{% load app_name %}` and the app will load its js in the html or does the user expecility need to write a `<script src='..'></script>` tag before using the app's template tags.

Answer (score 1):

Just put `<script ...>` in a template in your reusable app, and include that template in any app you want:

```
{% include "reusable_app/js_header.html" %}
```

The reusable app needs to be listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` to find the templates.